# How to remove the sash in this aluminum single hung window?

Tags: repair, windows, glass, glazing

EDIT: problem solved see below

I have a garden window with single hung sashes on both sides. The window frames are non thermally broken with single pane glass. The window is from early 90s but I don't know the manufacturer.

The glass in the operable sash on one side got broken. I want to remove the sash to work on replacing the glass.

I am trying to figure out how to remove the sash. To me it looks like it's not designed to be removed. I don't see any stops or removable clips within the track that would allow the sash to clear the track. However, there are rubber gaskets on the interior faces of the tracks where the sash rides up and down. I think I could pry out the gasket on one side without damaging it, and slide the sash over just enough to pop it out. On the interior facing jamb there is also a tiny cable which holds the window up. I can't even get a screwdriver close enough to remove it with the sash in place. So I plan to disconnect the cable when I (gently) pop the sash out.

Is anyone familiar with these windows? Do you know any alternative method to remove the sash? I included a couple photos of the good side below. Thanks!

EDIT: The top half of the "gasket" seated in the track was a removable hard plastic profile. It was fairly easy to pry out with a screwdriver. Then I slid the sash upwards and tilted out in about 5 seconds.

[image: interior photo of one side of the garden window]

[image: exterior photo of one side of the garden window]

[image: sash removed]

[image: broken glass]

Comment: Can make your edit into an answer.  You can answer your own question if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the black element in the track was a hard plastic profile that was split about halfway up the track. Therefore I was able to pry it out of the track. The cable attached to the sash also had a sheet metal clip that was quick to disconnect.

Once I removed the plastic stop in the track and disconnected the cable, I raised the sash as high as possible, and it tilted out of the track fairly easily.

[image]